# Retrieve Oracle last inserted IDENTITY

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

Since Oracle 12c we can use IDENTITY fields.

Is there a way to retrieve the last inserted identity (i.e. `select @@identity` or `select LAST_INSERTED_ID()` and so on)?

Comment: The `identity`  columns still use a sequence in the background. You should be able to use the usual `sequence.currval` to obtain the last generated value.

Comment: The issue is that I have to know the name of the sequence. Actaully is hard to know the name of the table and the name of the schema where I inserted the records (the name of the sequence is related to them).

Comment: How can you _not_ know the name of the table you are inserting into?

Comment: You can also use the returning clause depending on exactly what you're trying to do - if you want the ID you just inserted that would possibly work for you, without needing to know the sequence name; if you want the last ID  inserted by anybody in any session you probably want to query the table. More context would be helpful.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm working on a library. The user (of the library) just works on tables and when he need to know the id he just ask for the id.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well. Oracle uses sequences and default values for IDENTITY functionality in 12c. Therefore you need to know about sequences for your question.

First create a test identity table.

```
CREATE TABLE IDENTITY_TEST_TABLE
(
  ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
, NAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) 
);
```

First, lets find your sequence name that is created with this identity column. This sequence name is a default value in your table.

```
Select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT from USER_TAB_COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'IDENTITY_TEST_TABLE';
```

for me this value is "ISEQ$$_193606"

insert some values.

```
INSERT INTO IDENTITY_TEST_TABLE (name) VALUES ('atilla');
INSERT INTO IDENTITY_TEST_TABLE (name) VALUES ('aydın');
```

then insert value and find identity.

```
INSERT INTO IDENTITY_TEST_TABLE (name) VALUES ('atilla');
 SELECT "ISEQ$$_193606".currval from dual;
```

you should see your identity value. If you want to do in one block use

```
declare
   s2 number;
 begin
   INSERT INTO IDENTITY_TEST_TABLE (name) VALUES ('atilla') returning ID into s2;
   dbms_output.put_line(s2);
 end;
```

Last ID is my identity column name.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. You just need to ensure that you're evaluating `<sequence_name>.currval` in the same session you're inserting in.

Comment: Illuminating answer. Until I read this answer I hadn't thought about the lack of a `currval` capability with IDENTITY columns - yet to use them in real life :( .

Comment: Is this solution safe against race condition: an other row inserted into the table between my insert and my seq value select on an other thread? Is it guaranteed somehow that my seq select will return the value generated during my insert and not the value generated in the other thread's one?

Comment: returning ID solution should be safe against race condition.

Answer (score 2):

`IDENTITY` column uses a `SEQUENCE` “under the hood” - creating and dropping sequence automatically with the table it uses. 
Also, you can specify start with and increment parameters using 
start with 1000 and increment by 2. It's really very convenient to use `IDENTITY` when you don't want to operate it's values directly.

But if you need to somehow operate sequence directly you should use 
another option available in Oracle 12c - column default values. Sutch default 
values could be generated from sequence `nextval` or `currval`. To allow you to have a comprehensible sequence name and use it as "identity" without a trigger.

```
create table my_new_table
(id number default my_new_table_seq.nextval not null)
```

You will be always able to call: `my_new_table_seq.currval`.

It is possible to get ID generated from `SEQUENCE` on insert statement using `RETURNING` clause.

For example, create a temporary table:

```
create global temporary table local_identity_storage ("id" number) on commit delete rows
```

Make some insert saving this value in the temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE identity_test_table (
  id_ident          NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  same_value VARCHAR2(100)
);

declare
  v_id number(10, 0);
begin  
  INSERT INTO identity_test_table
    (same_value)
  VALUES
    ('Test value')
  RETURNING id_ident INTO v_id;

  insert into local_identity_storage ("id") values (v_id);
  commit;
end;
```

Now you have "local" inserted id.

```
select "id" from local_identity_storage
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (....)
  VALUES (...)
  RETURNING pk_id INTO yourtable;
```

It will help you to retrieve last inserted row

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Oracle implemented `IDENTITY` just to say that they support identities. Everything is still implemented using `SEQUENCES` and sometimes you need to access the `SEQUENCE` to make some of the work (i.e. retrieve the latest inserted `IDENTITY`).

There is not a way to retrieve the `IDENTITY` similar to MySQL, SQL Server, DB2, and so on, you have to retrieve it using the `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: Yes, it is abstraction over SEQUENCE, but it will change the syntax of INSERT clause and this change will also be reflected in performance. Look at this test (inserting in Oracle 12c) using three different techniques (results taken from here[https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1]):
1) TRIGGER_IDENTITY : Time=217 hsecs CPU Time=204 hsecs;
2) DIRECT USAGE SEQUENCE: Time=26 hsecs CPU Time=22 hsecs;
3) REAL_IDENTITY    : Time=28 hsecs CPU Time=26 hsecs.

Comment: It was done to make migrations to Oracle Database easier. No need to manually create sequence and triggers to fire them on inserts - the database does that for you now. I don't speak for Oracle, but I do have a whitepaper on the subject if you're interested in what else we did in 12c to assist with migrations.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I'm exactly doing a migration but without a behaviour similar to other DBMS the work is hard.

Answer (score 1):

As I've written in [this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/07/16/how-to-fetch-all-current-identity-values-in-oracle/), you could fetch all the current identity values of your schema with a single query:

```sql
with
  function current_value(p_table_name varchar2) return number is
    v_current number;
  begin
    for rec in (
      select sequence_name
      from user_tab_identity_cols
      where table_name = p_table_name
    )
    loop
      execute immediate 'select ' || rec.sequence_name || '.currval from dual'
      into v_current;
      return v_current;
    end loop;

    return null;
  end;
select *
from (
  select table_name, current_value(table_name) current_value
  from user_tables
)
where current_value is not null
order by table_name;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your scope, global or last user inserted?
If global just use

```
SELECT mytable_seq.nextval MyTableID FROM DUAL
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/oracle-last-insert-id-question/1402

If specific encapsulate your inserts & query within a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The scope is the last user. I think that your suggestion works only for MySQL. In Oracle does not work (syntax error) also adding `FROM Dual` clause.

Comment: That's for global (I could also use current but is still global)

Answer (score -4):

the last insert will be the highest value of the column.
so I think that the easiest way to do it is with the max() method.
something like this

```
select max(id) from table_name
```