# How do I get the last id entered with Dapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, dapper

I'm querying DB Oracle and would like to return the entered id. I use a sequence that automatically generates the next id for me. I've already tried this, but I have an "ORA-00933 sql command terminated incorrectly" exception. What is the error? Thank you

```
public async Task<int> InsertSESSIONUSER_TAsync(SESSIONUSER_T obj)
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO SESSIONUSER_T (ID, USERNAME,PASSWORD,LOCALE,TIMEZONEID,EMAIL,CREATIONDATE, EMAILPEO) VALUES (USER_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,'TEMP',:PASSWORD,:LOCALE,:TIMEZONEID,:EMAIL,:CREATIONDATE,:EMAILPEO); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)";
        using (OracleConnection cnn = DBCConnectionFactory.Getconnection())
        {
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                int row = await cnn.ExecuteAsync(sql, obj);
                var result = await cnn.QueryAsync<int>(sql, obj);
                return result.Single();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ApplicationLogger.Logger.Error(ex, "InsertSESSIONUSER_TAsync");

            }
            finally
            {
                if (cnn?.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    cnn.Close();
                }

            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` was used in T-SQL before 2005 and the OUTPUT clause. It doesn't work in Oracle and shouldn't be used in T-SQL either

Comment: As this [possibly duplicate question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811283/retrieve-oracle-last-inserted-identity) you need to use .CURRVAL with the sequence that provides values for the key, eg `SELECT USER_SEQUENCE.CURRVAL FROM dual;`

Comment: Could you let me see a draft of how the query should be written? Because this thing is not clear to me. Thank you

Comment: The duplicate shows exactly that. The query should be `SELECT USER_SEQUENCE.CURRVAL FROM dual;`. Don't forget the semicolon either

Comment: I wrote this, but it throws me the same exception as before

string sql = @"INSERT INTO SESSIONUSER_T (ID, USERNAME,PASSWORD,LOCALE,TIMEZONEID,EMAIL,CREATIONDATE, EMAILPEO)
                VALUES ( USER_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,'TEMP', :PASSWORD, :LOCALE, :TIMEZONEID, :EMAIL, :CREATIONDATE, :EMAILPEO);  SELECT USER_SEQUENCE.CURRVAL FROM dual;";

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Post SOLVED! I used the transactions and everything worked! ;)

Comment: It is *really* odd that the presence of a transaction should somehow fix "command terminated incorrectly". Are you **sure** that's all you did?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL must have 2 clauses. The insert and the select last inserted id. This isn't DBMS agnostic, so for instance, in MySQL, it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO <table> (...) VALUES (...); SELECT last_insert_id();
```

And on the application side, you'd have to use Dapper's extension method `ExecuteScalarAsync`. For instance:

```
// ...
var lastId = await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<long>("INSERT INTO <table> (...) VALUES (...); SELECT last_insert_id();");
```

Comment: Nothing to do, it gives me the same exception. Thank you

Comment: @Elmoro actually your sql params must be written like `@param` instead of `:param. And the properties of the object used to hold their values are case sensitive.

Comment: I have done other query inserts and the parameters it takes me as :param and not @param

Answer (score -2):

```
insert into your_table (...)
output INSERTED.(column name) 
values (...)
```

Comment: This is an Oracle question. The OUTPUT clause works only on SQL Server. Not my downvote by the way, but this answer doesn't apply